# How to open calendar with help of button in input field which has type="date"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `input field` with `type="date"`, and a `button`:

```
<input  type="date"  name="DateOfBirth"class="form-control"  ng-model="patient.DateOfBirth" format="dd/mm/yyyy"  required="true" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="patient.PatientId" ng-click="open()">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

So when I click the button, the calendar (date picker) should open. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one(bootstrap date picker)

```js
$scope.open = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope.opened = !$scope.opened;

  if ($("calenderselector").css("display") == "none") {
    $("calenderselector").show();
  } else {
    $("calenderselector").hide();
  }

};
```

```html
<input ng-change="onDateSelector()" id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" ng-disabled="patient.PatientId" ng-click="opened=!opened" type="text" placeholder="dd-MM-yyyy" max-date="{{maxDate}}" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="patient.DateOfBirth"
  is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" required="true" close-text="Close" />

<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your snippet included some AngularJS directives, I assume you use it in your code and I'm going to use it in my solution too.

You need to create the `open` method you're calling on `ng-click` into your `$scope` object. Inside said method, select the calendar element and trigger its `focus()` event to open the calendar.

Working code below:

```js
(function(){
  var app=angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.open=function(){
      document.getElementById('DateOfBirth').focus();
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as app">
  
  <input type="date" id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" class="form-control" ng-model="patient.DateOfBirth" format="dd/mm/yyyy" required="true" />
  
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="calendarButton" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="patient.PatientId" ng-click="open()">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
    
</body>
```

However, this can also be accomplished without JavaScript altogether; but to do that, you'll need to replace your `button` with a `label`. When a `label` gets clicked, it triggers the `input` element it's assigned to:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="date" id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" class="form-control" ng-model="patient.DateOfBirth" format="dd/mm/yyyy" required="true" />
  
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <label for="DateOfBirth" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="patient.PatientId" ng-click="open()">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </label>
</span>
```

Comment: Why are you using AngularJS in 2020?

Comment: I'm not. Did I say that I was?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way

1. Initialize `input[name="DateOfBirth"]` with your datepicker
2. Focus on the `input[name="DateOfBirth"]` on click event at the button

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Based on browser support:
A date picker can pop-up when you enter in input field.
</p>
<form action="date_demo.php">
Input type date test:
<input type="date" name="my_date">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<p><strong>Note:</strong>
type="date" is not supported in Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```